# Character count ignoring first characters in multiple strings

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string sentence;
    int countv = 0, countc = 0, countspace = 0, number, s = 1;
    cout << "How many sentence would you like to check? - ";
    cin >> number;
    
    while(s <= number)
    {
        cout << "\nSentence " << s << ":";
        cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, sentence);
        
        for(int i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            if(sentence[i] == 'a' || sentence[i] == 'e' || sentence[i] == 'i' || sentence[i] == 'o' || sentence[i] == 'u')
                countv++;
            else if(isspace(sentence[i]))
                countspace++;
            else
                countc++;
        }
        cout << "\nSentence " << s << " result:";
        cout << "\nThere are " << countv << " vowels in the sentence.";
        cout << "\nThere are " << countc << " consonants in the sentence.";
        cout << "\nThere are " << countspace << " whitespace in the sentence.";
        countc = 0, countv = 0, countspace = 0;
        s++;
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

I'm trying to count the number of vowels and consonants in multiple strings but, for some reason, it only gives the correct output for the first string.

I've noticed that, for the next strings (2nd, 3rd and so on), it does not count the first letter of the string. Why is this?

Comment: don't make your program interactive. don't write a while loop. do write several functions, for example countvowel(...), countspace(...) etc. when learning c__ (or any other language) you cannot write too many functions.

Comment: What is `cin.ignore();` doing? A read of [std::basic_istream::ignore](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) may be in order.

Answer (score 2):

The code is *ignoring* the first character of each of the strings after the first because you are *telling it to ignore* those on input … with the call to `cin.ignore()`. That call should **not** be *inside* the loop but immediately before it, so as to ignore the newline that is left in the input stream after the `cin >> number` extraction.

Note that the call to `getline` does not leave that newline in the stream's buffer; see [this cppreference page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline):

> … the next available input character is `delim`, as tested by
> `Traits::eq(c, delim)`, in which case the delimiter character ***is
> extracted from input***, but is not appended to `str`.

Here's a suitably modified version of your code:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::cin, std::cout;

int main()
{
    std::string sentence;
    int countv = 0, countc = 0, countspace = 0, number, s = 1;
    cout << "How many sentence would you like to check? - ";
    cin >> number;
    cin.ignore(); // Call ignore HERE (once) to skip the newline left in the buffer from the above!

    while (s <= number)
    {
        cout << "\nSentence " << s << ":";
     //  cin.ignore(); WRONG!
        std::getline(cin, sentence);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < sentence.length(); i++)
        {
            if (sentence[i] == 'a' || sentence[i] == 'e' || sentence[i] == 'i' || sentence[i] == 'o' || sentence[i] == 'u')
                countv++;
            else if (isspace(sentence[i]))
                countspace++;
            else
                countc++;
        }
        cout << "\nSentence " << s << " result:";
        cout << "\nThere are " << countv << " vowels in the sentence.";
        cout << "\nThere are " << countc << " consonants in the sentence.";
        cout << "\nThere are " << countspace << " whitespace in the sentence.";
        countc = countv = countspace = 0; // Nicer than the dodgy use of the comma!
        s++;
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that calling `cin.ignore()` with no parameter will merely skip the next character in the stream, which is not guaranteed to be a newline. For instance, if the user had typed ```123   [enter]``` then `ignore()` will skip a single space after `123` but leave the remaining spaces and newline in the buffer. To account for that, you would need to use `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` instead.